# I want to make it appear as if text is always the same distance away from circle

Tags: javascript, svg

My problem is that when i am rotating this svg i counter rotate the text to keep it horizontal. however this makes it look like it is further from the circle when the degree is for example 0 or 180 when its high above or below. but when its 90 its right next to it. i believe this is actually correct since the center of the text is the same distance away. is there a way to fix this?

```html
<svg
      height="200"
      viewBox="0 0 100 100"
      fill="none"
      transform="rotate(45, -16, -16)"
    >
      <circle
        cx="30"
        cy="30"
        r="5"
        fill="#FFFFFF"
        stroke="#3D3D3D"
        stroke-width="1.5"
      />
      <g transform="rotate(90, 20, 20)">
        <path
          d="M15.6528 7.06945L15.4939 7.36025L15.602 7.67352L17.8504 14.1941L2.3372 6.25279L18.9596 1.01652L15.6528 7.06945Z"
          fill="white"
          stroke="#3D3D3D"
          stroke-width="1.5"
        />
      </g>
      <text
        x="30"
        y="70"
        text-anchor="middle"
        font-size="14px"
        fill="#3D3D3D"
        pointer-events="none"
        font-weight={500}
        transform="rotate(-45, 30, 70)"
      >
         some text here
      </text>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Please try this: make cx and cy = 0 for the circle. Use this d attribute for the path: `d="M0,-25l6,15l-6,-3l-6,3z"` put the circle and the path in a group <g> and translate the group (30,30). Now you don't need to rotate the svg or transform the text

Answer (score 0):

Remember to set your [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform-origin), because they help solv this: if you want the text at a fixed distance, put it in a `<g>` with the circle's center as transform-origin, and a rotation transform, and then give the text element a rotation by the same angle in the opposite direction so that it stays upright.